# Media query to target iphone/mobile/ipad

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using media query to target iphone/ipad/mobile.

I have written the following media query.

But my problem is if i write css in media query of  mobile 'max-device-width : 480px' it will also apply to iphone.

Is i am doing wrong ??

```
For mobile : like samsung grand(480 * 800):

@media only screen 
    and (max-device-width : 480px)
    {

        }


For iphone:

@media only screen 
and (max-device-width : 320px) 
 {

 } 


For ipad:
@media screen and (min-width:760px)
 {

 }
```

Also added meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with below media query and meta tag

```
/* For mobile : like samsung grand(480 * 800): */
@media screen and (max-width : 480px){}


/* For iphone: */
@media screen and (max-width : 320px){} 


/* For ipad: */
@media screen and (max-width : 768px){}
```

Additionally. change your meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 1):

Rajnikant's answer is indeed the correct one, except that the iPad max-width is wrong. It should be 768px:

```
/* For ipad: */
@media screen and (max-width : 768px){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer from http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/

```
//HTC One, Samsung Galaxy S5, OnePlus One
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)

//Samsung Galaxy S2
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 534px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)

//Samsung Galaxy S3
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  

//Samsung Galaxy S4
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)  

//LG Nexus 4
@media screen and (device-width: 384px) and (device-height: 592px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)

//LG Nexus 5, Huawei Ascend P7
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 592px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)

//Asus Nexus 7
@media screen and (device-width: 601px) and (device-height: 906px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332)  

//iPad 1, iPad 2, iPad Mini
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)

//iPad 3, iPad 4
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 

//iPhone 3G
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  

//iPhone 4
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  

//iPhone 5

@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  

//iPhone 6
@media screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  

//iPhone 6 Plus
@media screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)  

//Huawei Ascend P6
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 592px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```