# Jquery and media queries

Tags: jquery, media-queries

Simple question - Is it possible to use jquery with media queries so the jquery only happens below a certain screen size.

I have a navigation that uses hover on the desktop but I need to use click on mobile.

I have few other actions I want to control on mobile like preventDefault() actions on buttons

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157088/media-query-to-target-iphone-mobile-ipad)

Comment: Check this out http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries

Comment: Bhushan - That is just how to use media queries. I'm asking how to use jquery with media queries

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the window is not very good.

The best approach is by using matchmedia

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 800px)")
if (mql.matches){ // if media query matches
 alert("Window is 800px or wider")
}
else{
 // do something else
}
```

P.S. make sure you downloaded Typescript

Answer (score 1):

@Mohamad Shiralizadeh

This is looking nice. However its only triggering on window resize. When you first load the page it doesn't trigger. So based on your example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
// do things when the document is ready
contentChanger();
// do things when the widow resizes 
$(window).resize(function () {
    contentChanger();
});


// change content based on viewport
function contentChanger() {
    // viewport is 320 pixels or smaller
    if ($(window).width() <= 320) {
        // do things here
    }

    // viewport is 375 pixels or smaller but bigger than 320 pixels
    if ($(window).width() <= 375 && $(window).width() > 320) {
        // do things here
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in resize function of the windows:

```
$(window).on('resize', function (e) {
    var width = $(window).width();

    if (width > 1024)
        // Codes
});
```